# The history of philosophy

Tags: discussion

[Questions about philosophical personalities](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/23872/why-did-marx-study-philosophy) - are closed

[Questions about the domain of past philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/23821/have-philosophers-claimed-that-atheists-can-be-closer-to-god-than-religious-hyp) - are closed

[Questions about history](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/23824/why-did-confucianims-survive-longer-than-mohism-in-china) - are lapped up

Which is fine but the rules say

> history of philosophy — the domains and personalities in the past
>   associated with philosophy

I do not understand how this can be charitably interpreted.

Comment: and e.g. why people are closing this question is beyond me http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/23880/what-happens-when-stuff-breaks

Comment: "the domain of philosophy" =/= the history of its practice